# flutter select return null sqlite

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm new on `SQLite` and `flutter`. I'm trying to access an `SQLite` database (which is on my computer in the project folder at `'~/Work/FlutterTest/ProjectTestFlutter/poa.db'`.

But I have `null` when I try to `cast` my `List` to `String`.

There is my code :

```
class _DbPageState extends State<DbPage> {
  String data;
  var databasesPath;
  String path;
  Database database;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                data = getRecords().toString();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
          new Text(
            data,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  Future<void> openDb() async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, '~/Work/FlutterTest/ProjectTestFlutter/poa.db');

    database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
  }

  Future<List<Map>> getRecords() async {
    List<Map> list = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tbl1');
    return list;
  }

  Future<void> closeDb() async {
    await database.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the database being opened correctly? Because in order to open a preinitialized db in Flutter, you need to copy it to the device from the assets folder in the first place. You are getting the path as a computer path, which should not work.

Comment: so you are trying to access a db file that is on your computer from an app running from your device?

Comment: getDatabasesPath will give you a path in your device. You should make your db file path something like databasesPath + '/poa.db'. But again, you should copy it first from the flutter assets bundle to that path.

Comment: @Martyns oh so no it not opened correctly though. Could you provide an answer, please?

Comment: @Ryosuke looks like a problem indeed.

Comment: @Itoun Were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When app starts for example, copy the db to your device.

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/poa.db");
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String dbPath = join(databasesPath, "poa.db");
await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

Remember to add the db file to the pubspec.yml, just as you would do with image resources.
After that you could open it from the widget with:

```
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String dbPath = join(databasesPath, "poa.db");
var database = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1);
```

Comment: @Itoun That is great!